# How to make a macro that can insert html tags for paragraphs in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-2010

I have no experience in using vba. I am not a programmer. I have been writing articles in word and submitting them to a website where they require paragraphs to be enclosed by html tags.

I tried to make a macro that would insert these tags at the beginning and end of each paragraph but failed. I tried to do that by imitating other people's codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a macro that find begin and end of paragraph then replace any code